# Installing Oracle database in docker container

Tags: oracle, docker, rhel7

I am trying to install Oracle database software in RHEL7 Docker container.
Is such configuration supported?
I do not find any useful guide to do same.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, but as RDBMS is not yet tested or certified with Docker, there are no official resources available yet. Also, it's unlikely that you'd get full support for RDBMS within a container (either Docker or generic LXC) at this stage either.
This guide should work:
http://blog.grid-it.nl/index.php/2014/05/16/installing-oracle-xe-in-a-docker-image/